# mysql Select returning zero

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
`SELECT SUM(`KN`) + SUM((COALESCE(`EUR`, 0)))*7.5 FROM log WHERE `KN` IS NOT NULL and `EUR` IS NOT NULL`
```

And it returns 0

SUM(`EUR`)* 7.5 should be zero but SUM(`KN`) is 60. So result should be 60.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, I want to add numbers and avoid counting NULL so where is null to set 0 that I can add values

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `IFNULL(column, 0)` - it converts nulls into zeros

Comment: Hi, I have tried, same thing, but when I do: `SELECT (SUM(EUR)* 7.5) FROM log WHERE EUR IS NOT NULL`  I get 0 as result, so this works?

Comment: Does this one return something? `select 7.5 * sum(ifnull(EUR, 0)) from log`

Comment: Hi, it returns 0 which is correct but I need to add it to get 60 in this case (sum of kn is 60)

Comment: Can you also try these? `select sum(ifnull(KN, 0)) from log` and then `select 7.5 * sum(ifnull(EUR, 0)) + sum(ifnull(KN, 0)) from log`

Comment: Frist one returns 60 and second one 60 also, so this would be solution, Thanks.
Tell me why with `WHERE KN IS NOT NULL and EUR IS NOT NULL` it returns zero in any case?

Comment: Well, "AND" causes this issue. It ignores records when both fields are null, but what if only of the fields is null?

Comment: OK, I think I got it. Thank you and now I see my mistake in start